# How do you edit a JComboBox dropdown arrow?

Tags: java, netbeans, jcombobox

How do you remove the background of a `JComboBox` dropdown arrow, leaving only the small triangle? The dropdown list was created using the `JComboBox` tool in Netbeans version 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Drew I don't think the OP wants the button to disappear - he just wants the button to have no visible manifestation other than the arrow triangle:

```
JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<>();
final Color bg = box.getBackground();
box.setUI(new BasicComboBoxUI() {
    @Override
    protected JButton createArrowButton() {
        JButton b = super.createArrowButton();
        b.setBackground(bg);
        b.setBorderPainted(false);
        return b; 
   }
});
```